# LINQ case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query that searches for a specific word in a sentence. But I want to have that specific word case insensitive. So that you can search for `Action` or `action`.

My Linq query looks like this:

```
var bookFilter = new List<Book> {
  new Book { Title = "LINQ in Action" },
  new Book { Title = "LINQ for Fun" },
  new Book { Title = "Extreme LINQ" } };

var titles = 
    from booksss in bookFilter
    where string.Equals(booksss.Title, 
                       "Action",
                       StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)           
    select booksss.Title;

ObjectDumper.Write(titles);
```

But there is nothing returned?

Comment: string.Equals will only return EXACT matches only, you need to use Contains. or booksss.Title.IndexOf("Action", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Comment: @Janus?? You speak about Contains. But in your solution you don't use Contains. Funny

Comment: What I meant is that there are various ways of doing it, you can either use Contains OR use IndexOf. So I've shown you an example of IndexOf but mentioned both methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to check if `Title` *contains* the string. However, `Contains` itself *doens't have* an overload with `StringComparison` parameter, but you can easily do with `IndexOf`.

```
  var bookFilter = new List<Book>() {
    new Book { Title = "LINQ in Action" },
    new Book { Title = "LINQ for Fun" },
    new Book { Title = "Extreme LINQ" } };

  ...

  var titles = bookFilter
    .Select(book => book.Title)
    .Where(title => title
       .IndexOf("Action", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this wouldn't work with something like Entity Framework though it's not clear that's used here.

Comment: @Dimitry. Thank you! Very nice

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this as an answer in case your data source is actually Entity Framework because that will not understand what to do with `string.IndexOf`. You have two options:

1. Make your database case insensitive. In SQL Server this means using one of the case insensitive collations.
2. Use `Contains` in combination with `ToLower` (or even `ToUpper` if you're a rebel):

   ```
   //Make sure the search value is lower case
   var search = "Action".ToLower();

   var titles =
       from booksss in bookFilter
       where booksss.Title.ToLower().Contains(search)
       select booksss.Title;
   ```

Comment: Also nice. Thank you

Comment: My only concern about this solution is that, depending on the size of the list, you will be creating many new strings which the garbage collector will eventually have to clean up.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Like I said in the answer, this is for when your data source is something like Entity Framework. EF will convert this query into SQL, there's no string creation or GC needed.